# MQTT sessions in database - how to make performant?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, database-design

I have an application that let's devices communicate over MQTT.
When two (or more devices) are paired, they are in a session (with a session-id)

The topics are for example:

```
session/<session-id>/<sender-id>/phase
```

with a payload like

```
{'phase': 'start', 'othervars': 'examplevar'}
```

Every session is logged into a mySQL database into the following format:

| **id** | **session-id** | **sender** | **topic** (example: phase) | **payload** | entry-time | ...

Now, when I just want to get a whole session I can just query by session-id.

Another view I want to achieve looks like this:

| **session-id** (distinct) | **begin time** | **end time** | **duration** | **success** |

*Success is a boolean; true when in the current session there is an entry where the payload has a 'phase':'success'. Otherwise it is not successful.*

Now I have the problem that this query is very slow. Everytime I want to access it, it has to calculate for each session if it was successful, along with the time calculation.

Should I make a script at the end of a session, to calculate this information and put it in another table? The problem I have with this solution is that I will have duplicate data.

Can I make this faster with indexes? Or did I just make a huge design mistake from the beginning?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Indexes?  Yes.  YES!

If `session-id` is unique, get rid of `id` and use `PRIMARY KEY(session_id)`.

`success` could be `TINYINT NOT NULL` with values 0 or 1 for fail or success.

If the "payload" is coming in as `JSON`, then I suggest storing the entire string in a column for future reference, plus pull out any columns that you need to search on *and index them*.  In later versions of MySQL, there is a `JSON` datatype, which could be useful.

Please provide some `SELECTs` so we can further advise.

Oh, did I mention how important indexes are to databases?

Comment: Session id is not unique, since it contains multiple lines of multiple sessions